# String simplify 3x count and print charcters Java program

Tags: java

Any one know this program.
Firstly I was unable to understand logic in that question please explain
                 Thank you.

Comment: The only info on the program you are talking about is the title, isn't it? You might want to provide more, it should increase your chance on answers and decrease the risk of being closed as "unclear".

Comment: *I was unable to understand logic in that question*. Neither did I. **What** is the question?

Answer (score 0):

Your question looks like you want to cut a string to 3 characters.
Example:

```
String s = "string";
System.out.println(s.substring(0, 3));
```

Tell me if I misunderstood the question. Also, please reread the question, you are misleading people.